# For loop nesting to update a Dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I'm having an issue with an exercise in which I'm asked to create a Dictionary (assignment 9.5 on Coursera python for everybody course). I have found the correct solution code, however I still don't understand what's the main problem with the one I have submitted, but I know the problem lies in how I nested a second for loop (line 10), which apparently is not required

here the rules of the exercise

*"Write a program to read through the **mbox-short.txt** and figure out who has sent the greatest number of mail messages. The program looks for 'From ' lines and takes the second word of those lines as the person who sent the mail. The program creates a Python dictionary that maps the sender's mail address to a count of the number of times they appear in the file."*

here my code (only the relevant part for the issue). When I run it the values of each key are way higher than they should be (example, one word appears 20 times on the document, yet if I run this code it's value will be 35)

```
handle = open(name)
indirizzi =dict()

for line in handle :
    if not line.startswith("From "):
        continue
    word = line.split()
    #the mistake is here
    for mail in word:
        mail = word[1]
        indirizzi[mail]= indirizzi.get(mail,0) +1
```

here the correct code which gives the right values

```
name = input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
    
handle = open(name)
emcount = dict()

for line in handle:
    if not line.startswith("From "): continue
    line = line.split()
    line = line[1]
    emcount[line] = emcount.get(line, 0) +1
```

Comment: What is the reason you are iterating over `word`? I would assume an email can only be from a single sender so you could just drop the `for` loop. Also, for each inner loop you are iterating all of the words in `line`, but you are picking first index each time, causing you to have more hits per email address than you should.

Comment: You're looping over the lines of the file. Then for each of the lines that starts with "From " you are looping over each word in that line. But instead of actually using each word, you are looking at the second word multiple times. (Once for each word in the line)

Answer (score 0):

Drop the iteration over `word`. How can you tell that's the issue? Nothing inside the loop uses the loop variable:

```py
    for mail in word:
        # word doesn't change, and mail is overwritten
        # by this assignment
        mail = word[1]
        indirizzi[mail]= indirizzi.get(mail,0) +1
```

So the iteration is giving you false duplicates